# Restart after blue screen BCCode 100007e

Tags: windows-xp, bsod

I need some help because I would like to solve problems connected to some recently restart after a blue screen on my PC (Desktop).
The error code was

- BCCode : 1000007e
- BCP1 : C0000005
- BCP2 : 00000000
- BCP3 : BA507C2C
- BCP4 : BA507928
- OSVer : 5_1_2600
- SP : 3_0
- Product : 256_1

**My Operating system:**

- Windows Xp Professional 32 bit
- Version 5.1 (build 2600.xpsp_sp3_gdr.120821-1629 : Service Pack 3)
- Service Pack 3

**My Hardware:**

- AMD Phenom II X4 955 Black Box 125W
- Asus M4A785TD-M
- EVO-Radeon HD5770 1GB GDDR5
- Asus CoolerMaster GX 650W
- G.Skill 2x2GB PC3-12800 1600Mhz-787 4GBECO
- SAMSUNG HD 3,5 SATAII 320GB SAMSUNG HD322GJ 7200rpm
- 16MB Western Digital 1TB SATAII 64MB
- CoolerMaster cm690 II    Advanced Tower Black
- 3 x Enermax Everest 120mm Blue Led
- Arctic    Freezer A30

Using BlueScreenView as suggested the following image display the results of the latest Bluescreen

[image: blue screenview dump report]

Comment: refer [How to diagnose Blue Screens in Windows 7 (64bit)](http://superuser.com/q/28448), [Any advice on what to do when getting a cryptic blue screen in windows?](http://superuser.com/q/213) and [PC Blue Screens and then instantly reboots. How do I stop this or find the error later?](http://superuser.com/q/42386) for some pointers

Comment: Uhm, are you system specs there to brag? They don't really have anything to do with the bluescreen.

Comment: Hello Joey, my system spec are showed because I'm afraid about the Pc heating...maybe some of my Hardware could increase the internal heat and cause the blue screen?

Comment: portcls.sys is an audio driver - you may want to try updating your audio drivers (or rolling back if you recently updated)

Comment: After browsing about bsod connected with portcls.sys I download this microsoft hotfix (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/950616) that have unzip "something" on my PC. Hoping to had solved the problem I will check in these next days if all was solved