# Need help diagnosing cause of BSOD

Tags: windows-7, windows, bsod, hardware-failure

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Any advice on what to do when getting a cryptic blue screen in windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/213/any-advice-on-what-to-do-when-getting-a-cryptic-blue-screen-in-windows)

I've got a Windows 7 PC here that was getting very frequent BSODs. The error codes were variant (IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL, PAGE_FAULT_IN_NONPAGED_AREA, ATTEMPTED_WRITE_TO_READONLY_MEMORY), and it was impossible to use the computer for longer than an hour without getting one. I backed it all up and reinstalled Windows completely, thinking that it was a corrupt driver issue. Unfortunately, I'm still getting the BSODs with the same error messages on this fresh installation.

This tells me that it must be some faulty piece of hardware, but I'm not sure what it would be. I ran Memtest+ on the machine, but did not get any errors after 2 passes. I also ran a few built-in recovery mode scans from the HP recovery partition. I need some ideas on how to test the rest of the hardware to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the following tool from NirSoft

http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/blue_screen_view.html

?

BlueScreenView scans all your minidump files created during 'blue screen of death' crashes, and displays the information about all crashes in one table. For each crash, BlueScreenView displays the minidump filename, the date/time of the crash, the basic crash information displayed in the blue screen (Bug Check Code and 4 parameters), and the details of the driver or module that possibly caused the crash (filename, product name, file description, and file version). 
For each crash displayed in the upper pane, you can view the details of the device drivers loaded during the crash in the lower pane. BlueScreenView also mark the drivers that their addresses found in the crash stack, so you can easily locate the suspected drivers that possibly caused the crash.

I have used it a few times and it is a great tool for figuring out the root cause of BSODs..

Comment: In addition, there is also this page you help you read the minidumps if you need more information about the crash: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315263

Comment: Yes, I have already used BlueScreenView and most crash reports appeared to be accusing ntoskrnl.exe. But, like I said, even after restoring the whole operating system, I am still experiencing the BSODs. I would imagine this rules out a corrupt driver as the culprit; is this a correct assumption?

Comment: It may not be corrupt, but there still could be some sort of conflict. You'll have to analyze the dump to see what part of the code is tripping up.